# megaraid 8308ELP upgrade Recommendation

Tags: raid, lsi

I have a [Gateway E-9525R](http://support.gateway.com/s/Servers/COMPO/Cases/1205110R/1205110Rnv.shtml) 2U, and I am looking to replace the raid card (an LSI 8308ELP)

What I need (in order of necessity) is

- Vsphere Esx 5 compatibility
- Dual SFF-8087 (as it has a 6x backplane)
- 3tb+ support
- sata 6gps (optional)

I am very new to the server realm, (student, that just bought the box off eBay for $99, experimenting with Vsphere) so any recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the dual SFF-8087, but have you checked out the recent Adaptec cards?

My desktop (OK, workstation) runs with an Adaptec 5405E. I'm using SATA 6GB/s not SAS, but I see that the 5405 does actually have *one* SFF-8087 connector only. That's too bad. Look: http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/products/controllers/hardware/sas/performance/sas-5405/

Funny thing; both my dedicated server *and* my desktop are using this same card. If Adaptec doesn't offer a comparable card with two or more SFF-8087 connectors, then I'd fall over stunned.

Apparently their current flagship product is the 6805: http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/products/controllers/hardware/sas/value/sas-6805/ It claims SAS 2.0 support. Very nice.

The Series 6 wasn't out when I bought my card, so I can't provide an honest customer review. But I have a very high praise overall for both Series 4 and Series 5 Adaptec hardware RAID cards from the perspective of someone who builds insanely high-spec workstations in a desktop form factor. Even without server-grade airflow, these things never overheat on me.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [VMware Compatibility Guide](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php).  The [IO Devices](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=io) category will tell you what brands, makes and models of cards are compatible.